# LaTeX listing counter counts with every \pause-command?

Tags: pause, beamer, listings

I'm writing a TeX-File for a beamer presentation and have a problem with the `\pause`-command and the listing counter:

The Listing counter increments its count with every `\pause` command – although I don't change the frame or anything at the code. This looks very ugly. So I need to either stop the counter from incrementing its count with every `\pause` command or turn off the counter at all – and I couldn't even find out how this works.

Can someone please help me?

Here some of my listings-Setting:

```
\definecolor{kit-gray}{RGB}{224,224,224}
\definecolor{kit-green}{RGB}{32,149,128}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{courier}
\lstset{
     basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, 
     numbers=left,              
     numberstyle=\tiny,         
     %stepnumber=2,                 
     numbersep=5pt,              
     tabsize=2,                         
     extendedchars=true,         
     breaklines=true,               
     %keywordstyle=\color{red},
     frame=t,         
 %frameround=tftf, 
     keywordstyle=[1]\textbf,       
     stringstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,     
     showspaces=false,              
     showtabs=false,                
     xleftmargin=17pt,
     framexleftmargin=17pt,
     framexrightmargin=6pt,
     framexbottommargin=4pt,
     backgroundcolor=\color{kit-gray},
     commentstyle=\color{kit-green},
     showstringspaces=true          
     %numberbychapter=false
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question a proper [minimal working example](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) illustrating the problem.

Comment: I simply wouldn't use a caption: the frame title is sufficient to tell what listing you're talking about. Members of the audience won't recall reference by numbers anyway.

Answer (score 5):

As you are aware, beamer will create a new page for each overlay. Each time a page containing a lstlisting environment is created the counter `lstlisting` is incremented. As this goes for any counter (tables, figures, etc.) beamer supports resetting the counter on overlays. Place

```
\resetcounteronoverlays{lstlisting}
```

in the preamble and your problem should be resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you typeset a regular `lstlisting` on a frame with a caption, this caption is rendered after every `\pause` command, incrementing the listing number (counter `lstnumber`).

The best option here is to set a label to the counter and then reference it as a manual caption made to look similar to when you're using the traditional `caption={...}` key-value. Rather use the `title={...}` key-value. Here is the idea in MWE form using the `article` document class (since no MWE was provided):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}% http://ctan.org/pkg/listings
\begin{document}
\setcounter{lstnumber}{0}\refstepcounter{lstnumber}\label{mylisting}% Correct listing reference
\begin{lstlisting}[title={Listing~\ref{mylisting}:\ This is a caption},language=C]
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  printf("Hello world!\n");
  return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}​
```

[`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) sets the starting value of `lstnumber` to `1` (in contrast to other environments that uses counter (initialized to `0`). So, we first set it to `0` using `\setcounter{lstnumber}{0}`, then increment it with a correct reference using `\refstepcounter{lstnumber}`. This sets it to `1`, and then we label it using `\label{mylisting}` (or something similar). Subsequently use `Listing~\ref{mylisting}: ...` as the `title` to provide the correct reference.

You may have to manually increment the counter after your listing if you use more listings later in your `beamer` presentation. If needed, use `\stepcounter{lstnumber}`. Note also that the counter setting/incrementing should be done outside (before) the `frame` environment to avoid multiple references.